# what should I do when I come across the error: invalid operands to binary & and error: invalid operands to binary |?

Tags: c

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SIGBAD(signo)   ((signo) <= 0 || (signo) >= NSIG)

int sigaddset(sigset_t  *set, int signo)
{
        if (SIGBAD(signo)) { errno = EINVAL; return(-1);}

        *set |= 1 << (signo - 1);
        return 0;
}

int sigdelset(sigset_t *set, int signo)
{
        if (SIGBAD(signo)) { errno =EINVAL; return -1; }

        *set &= ~(1 << (signo - 1));
        return 0;
}

int sigismember(const sigset_t *set, int signo)
{
    if (SIGBAD(signo)) { errno = EINVAL; return -1; }

    return ((*set & (1 << (signo -1))) != 0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing manual signal bit handling? Surely there are system macros for that already?

Comment: Well, you could stop treating opaque types as integers, for starters.

Comment: where did you take this code? mm I think he has problems in compiling existing code (linux kernel?). he maybe just needs the right compiler options.

Comment: can you with parenthesis around *set? like `(*set)`

Answer (score 3):

This means you're trying to do bit operation on something that's not an integer, but e.g. a struct.

for a `sigset_t` there already exist functions named [sigaddset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sigaddset.html) ,  [sigdelset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sigdelset.html)  and [sigismember](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sigismember.html), you should not re-implement them. `sigset_t` is an opaque thing, you shouldn't poke around in it with other but the sigXXXset() functions

Answer (score 2):

> Data Type: sigset_t
>
> The sigset_t data type is used to represent a
> signal set. Internally, it may be implemented as either an integer or
> structure type.
>
> For portability, use only the functions described in this section to
> initialize, change, and retrieve information from sigset_t
> objects—don't try to manipulate them directly.

**EDIT:** here are my thoughts. You are probably trying to compile code copied from somewhere (a book, open source, etc). Those functions already exist in the libraries, and should not be rewritten. But if you really want to do that, then keep in mind that the original code writer made the assumption that sigset_t was an integer or an integral type, not a struct.

Since in the system you are compiling with sigset_t may be (and I'm quite sure it is) defined as a structure, the code won't compile.

Possible solutions:

1. redefine your sigset_t as an integer (don't include the system headers where the original sigset_t is defined)
2. change the code to compile with the defined sigset_t, like in the example below (super-dangerous).

```
int sigaddset(sigset_t  *set, int signo)
{
        if (SIGBAD(signo)) 
        { 
            errno = EINVAL; 
            return(-1);
        }
            
        set->bits |= 1 << (signo - 1);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix the code.

The bitwise `&` and `|` operators require integers on both sides (two integer operands).

You seem to be (re-)implementing standard library functions.  Therefore, you must be privy to the internals of type `sigset_t`, but it is not clear what its type is.  If you don't know what the details of the type are, you have no business reimplementing the functions.

On Mac OS X, if you track far enough through the system headers, `sigset_t` is a `__uint32_t`, so the code above looks like it should work. If `sigset_t` is not in fact an integer on your machine, then your code will fail with errors similar to what you're getting.  So, unless you *are* implementing the library, you should be leaving well alone and using what the library provides and not writing your own bootleg version of the standard functions.